# FFmpeg or PHP-FFmpeg 0.19.0 : How to merge video file and audio file(mp3)

Tags: ffmpeg

How to drop current audio of video and merge this video with other audio file(mp3) using PHP-FFmpeg or FFmpeg command.

- case 1: duration of audio is 8 minute, video is 22 second. in this case : loop video when audio end.
- case 2: duration of audio is 8 minute, video is 10 minute. in this case : when audio end will stop and save a new mp4 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kinda need two different commands for each case but both are pretty simple:
Case 1:
[`-stream_loop -1`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#toc-Main-options) loops a file indefinitely; other options used in this will be explained in case 2

`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -shortest -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy output.mp4`

Case 2:
For this you should use the [`-shortest`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#toc-Options-for-filters-with-several-inputs-_0028framesync_0029) flag, which forces the output to terminate when the shortest input terminates.

The -map feature makes this easy.

This whole question is nice because both cases allow for *extremely* fast execution, as a reencoding is not necessary. (make sure to pass `-c copy` to take advantage of this!)

here is a oneliner:
`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -shortest -c copy -map 0:v -map 1:a output.mp4`

Comment: Great work ^^! tks